# Thymeleaf having problems using hash in the url

Tags: thymeleaf

I need to compose a URL like this with Thymeleaf:

> www.app.com/#/confirm/registration?token=12435nvds

but when I add the attribute with

`th:href="@{__${baseUrl}__/confirm/registration(token=${token})}"`

the url becomes:

> www.app.com/token=12435nvds#/confirm/registration

How can I escape the #?

Comment: Did you try: `<a th:href="@{__${baseUrl}__}/#/confirm/registration(token=${token})}">URL</a>` Otherwise, you can try to use the literal with plus characters: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html.  Or if you don't get a quick answer, you can always generate it server-side and add it to the model.

Comment: The last way is not suggested typically, but it gets the job done in a bind.

Comment: Concatenate the # with the urls.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many different ways, but the only way I managed to do it was this:

```
<a th:href="${baseUrl} + @{/confirm/registration(token=${token})}">my link</a>
```

HTH